# How do I view an older version of an SVN file?

Tags: svn, rollback, revision

I have an SVN file which is now missing some logic and so I need to go back about 40 revisions to the time when it had the logic I need. Other than trying to view a diff of the file in the command line (*very hard to read*), is there any way I could get a copy of that file to review so I can study it to recover parts?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You can update to an older revision:

```
svn update -r 666 file
```

Or you can just view the file directly:

```
svn cat -r 666 file | less
```

Comment: `svn cat -r 666 file | less` is perfect so I can read through it with vim!

Comment: @sillyMunky Try `svn cat | vim -`. If vim's syntax highlighting doesn't automatically kick in, do `:set syntax=java` (or whichever language).

Comment: Thanks very much John, actually I'm on debian and I found there's a nice little syntax highlighting package called 'source-highlight' so less can automagically pickup syntax highlighting (actually I now alias this to lesss for distinction).

Comment: svn cat -r 666 file > file_666.js if you would like to view that entire file :p

Comment: or if you are using bash 
`vim +set\ ft=<FILETYPE> <( svn cat -r <REV> <FILE> )`

Answer (score 7):

It is also interesting to compare the file of the current working revision with the same file of another revision.

You can do as follows:

```
$ svn diff -r34 file
```

Answer (score 3):

Update to a specific revision:

```
svn up -r1234 file
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to view revisions is to use a program/app that makes it easy for you.  I like to use trac : http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion

It provides a great svn browser and makes it really easy to go back through your revisions.

It may be a little overkill to set this up for one specific revision you want to check, but it could be useful if you're going to do this a lot in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer the question of how to "get a copy of that file":

```
svn cat -r 666 file > file_r666
```

then you can view the newly created `file_r666` with any viewer or comparison program, e.g.

```
kompare file_r666 file
```

nicely shows the differences.

I posted the answer because the accepted answer's commands do actually not give a copy of the file and because `svn cat -r 666 file | vim` does not work with my system (`Vim: Error reading input, exiting...`)

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest versions of [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), you can actually view them without using the cmd prompt. On the file, simply right-click => Team => Switch to another branch/tag/revision. Besides the revision field, you click select, and you'll see all the versions of that file.